# SQL Server 2008, iiko rms

Tags: sql-server

Во время установки компонентов *iiko RMS*, как только доходит до *sql server 2008 r2* выходит сообщение

> unable to load plugin library please rebuild your project and make sure all required plug-ins are installed.

Завершить не удается установку. В чем проблема может быть?

ОС windows 7 32, Microsoft SQL Server Express 2008 R2